# HTML5 File API read as text and binary

Tags: javascript, file, html

I am currently working on the HTML5 File API, and I need to get binary file data.
`The FileReader`'s `readAsText`, and `readAsDataURL` methods work fine, but `readAsBinaryString` returns the same data as `readAsText`.

I need binary data, but im getting a text string. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**2022 update**: See explanation below for why the OP was seeing what they were seeing, but the code there is outdated. In modern environments, you'd use the methods on the `Blob` interface (which `File` inherits):

- [`arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) for reading binary data (which you can then access via any of the [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays))
- [`text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text) to read textual data
- [`stream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) for getting a [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) for handling data via streaming (which allows you to do multiple transformations on the data without making multiple passes through it and/or use the data without having to keep all of it in memory

Once you have the file from the file input (`const file = fileInput.files[0]` or similar), it's literally just a matter of:

```
await file.text(); // To read its text
// or
await file.arrayBuffer(); // To read its contents into an array buffer
```

(See [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) for an example of streams.)

You might access the array buffer via a `Uint8Array` (`new Uint8Array(buffer)`).

Here's an example of `text` and `arrayBuffer`:

```js
const $ = id => document.getElementById(id);

const fileInput = $("fileInput");
const btnRead = $("btnRead");
const rdoText = $("rdoText");
const contentsDiv = $("contents");

const updateButton = () => {
    btnRead.disabled = fileInput.files.length === 0;
};

const readTextFile = async (file) => {
    const text = await file.text();
    contentsDiv.textContent = text;
    contentsDiv.classList.add("text");
    contentsDiv.classList.remove("binary");
    console.log("Done reading text file");
};

const readBinaryFile = async (file) => {
    // Read into an array buffer, create
    const buffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
    // Get a byte array for that buffer
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    // Show it as hex text
    const lines = [];
    let line = [];
    bytes.forEach((byte, index) => {
        const hex = byte.toString(16).padStart(2, "0");
        line.push(hex);
        if (index % 16 === 15) {
            lines.push(line.join(" "));
            line = [];
        }
    });
    contentsDiv.textContent = lines.join("\n");
    contentsDiv.classList.add("binary");
    contentsDiv.classList.remove("text");
    console.log(`Done reading binary file (length: ${bytes.length})`);
};

updateButton();

fileInput.addEventListener("input", updateButton);

btnRead.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const file = fileInput.files[0];
    if (!file) {
        return;
    }
    const readFile = rdoText.checked ? readTextFile : readBinaryFile;
    readFile(fileInput.files[0])
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(`Error reading file:`, error);
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#contents {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <label>
            <span>File:</span>
            <input type="file" id="fileInput">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <input id="rdoText" type="radio" name="format" value="text" checked>
            Text
        </label>
        <label>
            <input id="rdoBinary" type="radio" name="format" value="binary">
            Binary
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="btnRead" type="button" value="Read File">
    </div>
</form>
<div id="contents"></div>
```

---

**Note in 2018**: `readAsBinaryString` is outdated. For use cases where previously you'd have used it, these days you'd use [`readAsArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) (or in some cases, [`readAsDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)) instead.

---

`readAsBinaryString` says that the data must be represented as a [**binary string**](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#binary-string), where:

> ...every byte is represented by an integer in the range [0..255].

JavaScript originally didn't have a "binary" type (until ECMAScript 5's WebGL support of [Typed Array](https://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/)* *(details below)* -- it has been superseded by ECMAScript 2015's [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer)) and so they went with a String with the guarantee that no character stored in the String would be outside the range 0..255. (They could have gone with an array of Numbers instead, but they didn't; perhaps large Strings are more memory-efficient than large arrays of Numbers, since Numbers are floating-point.)

If you're reading a file that's mostly text in a western script (mostly English, for instance), then that string is going to look a *lot* like text. If you read a file with Unicode characters in it, you should notice a difference, since JavaScript strings are [UTF-16](http://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html#UTF16)** *(details below)* and so some characters will have values above 255, whereas a "binary string" according to the File API spec wouldn't have any values above 255 (you'd have two individual "characters" for the two bytes of the Unicode code point).

If you're reading a file that's not text at all (an image, perhaps), you'll probably still get a very similar result between `readAsText` and `readAsBinaryString`, but with `readAsBinaryString` you *know* that there won't be any attempt to interpret multi-byte sequences as characters. You don't know that if you use `readAsText`, because `readAsText` will use an [encoding determination](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#encoding-determination) to try to figure out what the file's encoding is and then map it to JavaScript's UTF-16 strings.

You can see the effect if you create a file and store it in something other than ASCII or UTF-8. (In Windows you can do this via Notepad; the "Save As" as an encoding drop-down with "Unicode" on it, by which looking at the data they seem to mean UTF-16; I'm sure Mac OS and *nix editors have a similar feature.) Here's a page that dumps the result of reading a file both ways:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Show File Data</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function loadFile() {
        var input, file, fr;

        if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
            bodyAppend("p", "The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
            return;
        }

        input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
        if (!input) {
            bodyAppend("p", "Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
        }
        else if (!input.files) {
            bodyAppend("p", "This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
        }
        else if (!input.files[0]) {
            bodyAppend("p", "Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
        }
        else {
            file = input.files[0];
            fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = receivedText;
            fr.readAsText(file);
        }

        function receivedText() {
            showResult(fr, "Text");

            fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = receivedBinary;
            fr.readAsBinaryString(file);
        }

        function receivedBinary() {
            showResult(fr, "Binary");
        }
    }

    function showResult(fr, label) {
        var markup, result, n, aByte, byteStr;

        markup = [];
        result = fr.result;
        for (n = 0; n < result.length; ++n) {
            aByte = result.charCodeAt(n);
            byteStr = aByte.toString(16);
            if (byteStr.length < 2) {
                byteStr = "0" + byteStr;
            }
            markup.push(byteStr);
        }
        bodyAppend("p", label + " (" + result.length + "):");
        bodyAppend("pre", markup.join(" "));
    }

    function bodyAppend(tagName, innerHTML) {
        var elm;

        elm = document.createElement(tagName);
        elm.innerHTML = innerHTML;
        document.body.appendChild(elm);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action='#' onsubmit="return false;">
<input type='file' id='fileinput'>
<input type='button' id='btnLoad' value='Load' onclick='loadFile();'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use that with a "Testing 1 2 3" file stored in UTF-16, here are the results I get:

```
Text (13):

54 65 73 74 69 6e 67 20 31 20 32 20 33

Binary (28):

ff fe 54 00 65 00 73 00 74 00 69 00 6e 00 67 00 20 00 31 00 20 00 32 00 20 00 33 00
```

As you can see, `readAsText` interpreted the characters and so I got 13 (the length of "Testing 1 2 3"), and `readAsBinaryString` didn't, and so I got 28 (the two-byte [BOM](http://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html#UTF16) plus two bytes for each character).

---

* [XMLHttpRequest.response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response) with `responseType = "arraybuffer"` is supported in HTML 5.

** *"JavaScript strings are UTF-16"* may seem like an odd statement; aren't they just Unicode? No, a JavaScript string is [a series of UTF-16 code units](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.4); you see surrogate pairs as two individual JavaScript "characters" even though, in fact, the surrogate pair as a whole is just one character. See the link for details.

Comment: So it returns text encoded from 0-255? Is there a way to convert those characters to binary or hex data(0-1 or 0-FF)?

Comment: @digitalFresh: The string *is* the binary data. As you were commenting, I posted an example which may help. JavaScript doesn't have a "binary" type and so they went with a String with the guarantee that no character stored in the string would be outside the range 0..255. (They could have gone with an array of numbers instead, but they didn't.) The example shows how to get the raw value of a "character" from the string.

Comment: I tried this code with Chrome 7.0. The callback is never getting called. At the same time, there are no errors in debug window. Any help?

Comment: @morpheus: Works for me in Chrome 7. You sure you're clicking Load?

Comment: it works if i access the webpage like http://localhost/fileapitest.html, but doesn't work if you open the webpage using file:///C:/Users/morpheus/Desktop/fileapitest.html. Is this per spec? Thanks for the code.

Comment: @morpheus: Because this stuff is asynchronous, it can't throw exceptions; you need to look at the interface to see if there's some asynchronous way it reports errors. And indeed, `FileReader` has `onerror` for this. When you use a `file://` URL, your document domain is ~null, which tends to close you off from a lot of things (I don't know the details, I never do it), esp. when the SOP gets into it. I'm pretty sure it's up to the browser, at least for now, as the security part of the spec is still provisional: http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#security-discussion But I wouldn't expect it to work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried to read .doc and .pdf file using javascript readAsBinaryString method but it is not giving correct output but gave correct output from .txt file. is it possible to read .doc and .pdf?

Comment: @Parvathy: Sure, of course. You might want to post a question showing your code, showing what data you see, and saying why you think that isn't right.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my friendpost that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587553/cant-read-word-and-pdf-files-using-gwt

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt: Thanks, though, I did clarify my statement in the answer, since "JavaScript strings are UTF-16" seems like an odd statement on its own (UTF-16? why aren't they just Unicode?). :-)

Comment: Many thanks @T.J.Crowder -- I deleted my comment to prevent others from getting misled by my oversimplification, and thanks for posting the details - I am sure others will find your comments much more helpful (and reading the article is really a good idea, as you say, if one is mucking around in this area).

Comment: Lurkers - [Here's the article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding) Brian and I are talking about. Basically: JavaScript strings are [a series of UTF-16 code units](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.4), but they tolerate things like half a surrogate pair on its own and such, which leads Mathias (the author of the article) to think of them more like "UCS-2 with surrogates" (UCS-2 doesn't have surrogates). The article is interesting reading, as is the spec link above. I prefer to think of it like the spec does, but Mathias makes interesting points.

Comment: What happens with the bytes represented as `0` ? Does they disappear from the text string? One day I was trying to read a binary .bmp using its response text, but it only worked when I used array buffers.

Comment: @TheProHands: If you use `readAsBinaryString`, you'll get a string with characters in it with char code 0. See the fourth byte (and every other byte afterward) of the example.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah ! I checked it... Anyway, that happens cause of the server-side, right? I see