# how to read a text file using javascript without using activeX?

Tags: javascript, html, file, activex

how to read a text file using javascript without using activeX?

If there is no solution, then suggest some other solution to read file..

Comment: If you're looking to read local file on the users computer there is no other way than having the user upload the file if you don't want to use activex or java applet.

Comment: ...just because there is no way to do it doesn't mean this question is bad.  Obviously it was clear enough to answer.

Comment: This helps? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: we can do that using HTML5 fileAPI - FileReader.ReadAsText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can do that using HTML5 fileAPI - FileReader.ReadAsText

[HTML5 File API read as text and binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary)