# How GWT fileupload works?

Tags: gwt, file-upload

Anybody know how `GWT` file upload works? I know about `FileUpload` widget and how to use it. I want to know what is its inner mechanism. We can't get contents of file from `FileUpload` widget in client and how it is going to server? I googled it but i didn't get solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111130/basic-file-upload-in-gwt

Comment: Are you attempting to read the file on the client?

Comment: @AndyKing im attempting to read it in client and i want to know its full working

Comment: @Baadshah I want to know its internal working, i know code for it. but not understanding the way it went to server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**GWT's file upload**](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html) makes use [**HTML's input element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html). The html input element is native html dom element which allows to **select files from your system**.

After selection you need to submit it to your server. This is done by the GWT's [**FormPanel**](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html).

In particular, FileUpload is only useful when used within a FormPanel, because the browser will only upload files using ***form submission***.

**Note:**

**1)** You can read about how to code with formpanel and fileupload as answered here @ [Basic File upload in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111130/basic-file-upload-in-gwt)

**2)** If you are concerned with processing the file on client side and not pushing the file to server then you have limited options as mentioned here @ [How to retrieve file from GWT FileUpload component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053937/how-to-retrieve-file-from-gwt-fileupload-component)

Answer (score 0):

```
formPanel.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"uploadHandler");     
formPanel.setMethod(Method.POST);
```

when we use formPanel.submit(),we can invoke the servlet and get the file upload details.