# Can't read word and pdf files using gwt

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I want to read .doc and .pdf files in GWT client. I'm using the following package: `org.vectomatic.file`

The following is my code:

```
fileUpload.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
      uploadChecking();

      event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget();
      FileList fileList = FileList.fromEvent(event.getNativeEvent());
      FileReader reader = FileReader.create();
      File file = fileList.get(0);

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file, progressCallback);
  }
});

ProgressCallback progressCallback= new ProgressCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onError(ProgressEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoad(ProgressEvent e) {
            String result =e.getResult();
    }
}
```

If I am uploading a .txt file then it give correct data from file in `result`. When uploading PDF and .doc it gives some characters. Is there any way to get correct data or is there any way to read bytes directly from file because I think it can overcome this problem.

I want the file contents client side because it need some processing before going to server.

Comment: Both Microsoft Word documents with the file extension ".doc" and PDF documents are in binary format. Have you tried opening those files with a text editor? You should see that they are not readable text. Word ".docx" files are stored in a format that is more accessible - they can be unzipped and the unzipped files are readable. You could try porting a library like Apache [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org) and Apache [POI](http://poi.apache.org) to GWT, but that's a lot of work!

Comment: @AndyKing reading bytes from file will overcome this problem and java.nio.file have Files.readAllBytes() method. so is it gud way to emulate it?

Comment: @AndyKing there is no package in gwt for reading bytes from file?

Comment: @user2202354 The `org.vectomatic.file` project that you are using (from Google Code) seems to be the best solution currently, and it works. I think you are reading the .doc and .pdf files, but they are binary files, and so you'll have to do some work to read them as text. You could also look at the [Elemental](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/elemental) looks as though it could be good to use.

Comment: @Parvathy There is no way to use the `Files#readAllBytes` in GWT - you have to use the HTML5 File API. You can do this with `Elemental` or using another wrapper such as `org.vectomatic.file`. To access a file in the client's file system, outside the "sandbox", the user has to choose the file from an `input` control, or drag the file to a droppable target.