# Creating a Blob or a File from JavaScript binary string changes the number of bytes?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been playing with a few JS encryption libraries (CryptoJS, SJCL) and discovered problems related to the Blob/File APIs and JavaScript "binary strings".

I realized that the encryption isn't even really relevant, so here's a much simplified scenario. Simply read a file in using readAsBinaryString and then create a Blob:

```
>>> reader.result
"GIF89a����ÿÿÿÿÿÿ!þCreated with GIMP�,�������D�;"
>>> reader.result.length
56
>>> typeof reader.result
"string"
>>> blob = new Blob([reader.result], {type: "image/gif"})
Blob { size=64, type="image/gif", constructor=function(), more...}
```

I have created a JSFiddle that will basically do the above: it simply reads any arbitrary file, creates a blob from it, and outputs the length vs size:
http://jsfiddle.net/6L82t/1/

It appears that, when creating the Blob from the "binary (javascript) string", something with character encoding ends up munging the result.

If a non-binary file is used, you will see that the lengths of the Blob and the original binary string are identical.

So there is something that happens when trying to create a Blob/File from a non-plaintext Javascript string, and I need whatever that is to not happen. I think it may have something to do with the fact that JS strings are UTF-16?

There's a (maybe) related thread here:
[HTML5 File API read as text and binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary)

Do I need to possibly take the decrypted results (UTF-16) and "convert" them to UTF-8 before putting them in a Blob/File?

Working with someone in #html5 on Freenode, we determined that if you read an ArrayBuffer directly and then create the blob from that by first using a Uint8Array, the bytes work out just fine. You can see a fiddle that essentially does that here:
http://jsfiddle.net/GH7pS/4/

The issue is, at least in my scenario, I am going to end up with a binary string and would like to figure out how to directly convert that into a Blob so that I can then use html5's download to allow the user to click to download the blob directly.

Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that your post [already has a comprehensive edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23795034/revisions), right?  You can get the exact time stamp of any time posted on an SE web page by hovering over it; try that with the "asked 2 hours ago" above your name.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> It appears that, when creating the Blob from the "binary (javascript) string", something with character encoding ends up munging the result.

Yes. [That post you read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3146509/1048572) explains well how a "binary string" is constituted.

The [`Blob` constructor](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#constructorBlob) in contrast does

> 1. Let `s` be the result of converting [the string] to a sequence of [Unicode
>      characters](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.2.0/) using the algorithm
>      for doing so in [WebIDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/).
> 2. Encode `s` as [UTF-8](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-UTF-8) and append the resulting bytes to [the blob].

---

> We determined that if you read an ArrayBuffer directly and then create the blob from that by first using a Uint8Array, the bytes work out just fine.

Yes, that's how it is supposed to work. Just do the encryption on a Typed Array where you deal with the bytes individually, not on some string.

> The issue is, at least in my scenario, I am going to end up with a binary string

Again: Try not to. [binary strings are deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsBinaryString).

> I would like to figure out how to directly convert a binary string into a Blob. Do I need to possibly take the decrypted results (UTF-16) and "convert" them to UTF-8 before putting them in a Blob/File?

No, better don't try to do any string conversions. Instead, construct a [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Uint8Array)(Uint8Array) for the bytes that you want to get from the binary string.

This should do it (untested):

```
var bytes = new Uint8Array(str.length);
for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++)
    bytes[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
```

Comment: That totally worked.

I guess the follow-up question pertains specifically to CryptoJS -- when you decrypt the contents and receive your "WordArray", is there a way to go directly to an ArrayBuffer without first converting to a string and then putting that in a Uint8Array to use for the blob?

Comment: Follow-on: It looks like someone did something that doesn't involve a string conversion first (operates on bytes):

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/crypto-js/TOb92tcJlU0/Eq7VZ5tpi-QJ

Seems like this works. Awesome!

Comment: Yeah, that might be a good separate question (tagged [tag:cryptojs]). I didn't know they have their own datatypes, I'd have to look such things up in their documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the conversion to byte array from binary string!