# Text File to Var in Chrome - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

**Final product:** take a file called *theFile.txt* which is **saved with the js and HTML file** and have it broken up by line **into an array**.

**Problem:** Works fine in Firefox but revives the following error **in Google Chrome**:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/*(my name)*/Documents/testFile/theFile.txt. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.*

**Javascript code:**

```
$('#infoStore').load('theFile.txt', function(result) {
text = result;
console.log('here: '+text);});
```

**HTML code for infoStore:**

```
<div id="infoStore" hidden="true"></div>
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance. I will be online to answer questions often.

Answer (score 1):

That's because Chrome treats all origins using the `file:` protocol as being different from each other, and so the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) comes into play. It's just a security choice distinction between Chrome and some other browsers.

You basically can't use ajax with local files served via the `file:` protocol. (In Chrome.)

You could *read* the file using the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary/3146509#3146509) shows how), but of course that has limitations (not least that the user has to give you the file to read, either via `<input type="file">` or drag and drop).

Comment: What would you suggest as a substitute?

Comment: @user3605309: I've just added a suggestion.

Comment: not what I wanted to hear, but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of [Same-Origin-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You should load that file from webserver, not from local directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access local file in chrome ??
Sometimes it’s cool to debug and test javascript applications in Chrome but you want to read / write to local files. Example: you’re looking to use ajax and do a $.getJSON(‘json/somefile.json’). Chrome by default won’t allow this and will throw an error similar to

```
Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Or
XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Chrome does have a switch to enable this, it’s quite easy to turn on. You’ll need to make sure Chrome is closed completely, and run chrome with the ‘–allow-file-access-from-files’ flag. Ie:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application>
chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Or you should be able to run:

```
%localappdata%\google\chrome\application\chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

I’ve made the below into a .bat file I use, if you find it helps.

```
start "chrome" %localappdata%\google\chrome\application\chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
exit
```

To see if the flag is set, you can visit:  `chrome://version/` and look at the Command Line section and you should see –allow-file-access-from-files

You’ll most likely need to run this with at least admin access, and I would caution visiting unknown sites with this setting on, as they could capitalize on your setting and potentially read local files.

REF: [Reference Link -Allow Local File Access in Chrome (Windows)](http://chrisbitting.com/2014/03/04/allow-local-file-access-in-chrome-windows/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately not too useful when trying to make a public website.

Comment: if you want to create website public then you should not call any file from your local pc..

Comment: I am currently making the website, the files will be on the server once the site is live