# get File object from local file

Tags: javascript, file

From html page, I select a "file index" text file in a local folder (element input type="file").This file list several file names located in the same current folder.
How, in javascript, can I get a File descriptor from these other files from their file names ?
I try with following code, but I don't know what to do after:

```
function GetFileHandleFromUrl(localURL) {
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('GET', localUrl, false);
http.send(null); // success, return file content

var myFile = ???;
return myFile;
```

Answer (score 1):

> How...can I get a File descriptor from these other files from their file names ?

You can't. You can read the file and get the names from it using the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) (I demonstrate it in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary/3146509#3146509)), but you can't then get `File` instances for those other files in any standard way. The File API only grants you access to files the user has *explicitly* chosen to give you access to, via an `input type=file`.

Comment: Ok, but If I succeed to read the file content with my code : var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); http.open('GET', localUrl, false); http.send(null); http.response... Can I build a temp file and then create a File descriptor ?

Comment: @camillerufu: Again: No, you can't. Also note that many browsers will prevent your using a local URL (if by "local" you mean `file://...`), because of the SOP.

Comment: Ok, perhaps you are write. But I have my solution. I can work with the content of the file. http.response is enough for me.