# Using Javascript Read Bytes of Any Hosted File

Tags: javascript, file-io

Using Java Script we can read a file (selected using type="file") bytes by bytes of any file using myfile = new FileReader();.

This page has a nice example : [HTML5 File API read as text and binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary)

My question is can we do similar stuff using any file which is already hosted in any server like

http://localhost/file.bin

Answer (score 0):

you can't unfortunately, the `fileReader` api is for local files only.

you do have some options thogh, you could use a http/xhr request to download a online resource, save it to a local server and then pass the local file path to the fileReader api, but you can't do it directly from a URL

Comment: Any other API for that ?

Comment: not in js, your best bet is server code to download the asset