# get name of files of zip file in javascript

Tags: javascript, zip, filenames, unzip

In my application i have a form with some fields and  an `input file` field, and once the user upload a `zip file` i want to get the names of files that are contained in this `zip file`.

This is the form:

```
<input type="text" name="code" value="CodeValue">
<input type="text" name="Comment" value="commentValue">
<input type="file" name="zipFile" value="zipValue" accept="application/zip" 
       onchange="getzipFilesNames();" id="file-input">

<script>
    function getzipFilesNames() {

    }
</script>
```

I don't need to extract the files, i only need their names. How can i do this using javascript ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an easy way to do it using the [JSUnzip](https://github.com/augustl/js-unzip) library and the [JSInflate](https://github.com/augustl/js-inflate) library : This is a sample code:

```
        var filesInput = document.getElementById("file-input").files[0];
        var res;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(filesInput);

        reader.onloadend = function(e){
            var myZip = e.target.result;                 
            var unzipper = new JSUnzip(myZip);

            unzipper.readEntries();    
            var myFiles = unzipper.entries;    

            for(var i=0; i<myFiles.length; i++) {
                var name = myFiles[i].fileName; // This is the file name
                var content = JSInflate.inflate(myFiles[i].data); // this is the content of the files within the zip file.
            }
        }
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this requires the whole zip file to be loaded. Is there a way to just get the list of files without loading the while file, either by only reading the initial part of the file (assuming there is a list of contents at the beginning), or by reading the zip in chunks?

Answer (score 1):

JSUnzip and JSInflate are no longer maintained. I had issues using jszip to read the filenames of my large zip files, as jszip does not support files over 2GB, [according to its maintainer](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/799#issuecomment-1180668876).

I found a way to read filenames of the zip's contents using [zip.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zip.js/zip.js):

```js
import { BlobReader, ZipReader } from "@zip.js/zip.js";

async function getFileNamesFromZip(fileBlob) {
  const zipReader = new ZipReader(new BlobReader(fileBlob));
  const entries = await zipReader.getEntries();
  return entries.map((entry) => entry.filename);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To do this client-side you'll need to read the file using the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary/3146509#3146509) for examples), and then interpret the zip data to extract the filenames. There are libraries that can help with that second part, such as [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/).

Comment: thanks for your answer. unfortunately, i am not familiar with `javascript`, can you provide an example with the `jszip` libray, so i can use it directely in my application

Answer (score -2):

function readFiles() {
        var files = document.getElementById('files').files[0];

```
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsBinaryString(files)

    reader.onload = (e) => {
        var myZip = e.target.result            
        var unzipper = new JSUnzip(myZip);            
        var readEntries = unzipper.readEntries();
        var myFiles = unzipper.entries;

        for(var i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {
            var name = myFiles[i].fileName;
            console.log('filename = ', name)                             
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a copy/paste of the existing accepted answer, with a trivial change of console.log versus putting the files in to a local variable.