# Access C# Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I have created ActiveX Control that will convert file into bytes array.
I am consuming that activeX in my web application using javascript.In IE8 I am able to get byte array for the file but above IE8 it's giving undefined while returning.

I am posting my javascript code below

```
function CallFunction() {

            var obj = document.Adstringo;
            var filepath = document.getElementById("Fileupload1").value;            
            obj.Source = filepath;        
            var res = obj.GetFileBytes();  // Call ActiveX Function   
}
```

In res variable I am getting undefined in IE version greater than 8. In IE8 it is working properly.

I have tried changing the data types for the function in activeX.

I have changed from object to byte[]

Comment: ActiveX on web browsers is dead. IE8 was the last version of IE that supported non-whitelisted ActiveX objects. IE9 - IE11 supported a small number of whitelisted objects, although you could allow more via "ActiveX filtering." Edge doesn't support them at all. Neither do Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Konqueror, Midori, etc.

Comment: If you want to convert a file to a byte array, good news! You can do that without ActiveX using the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). [Here's an example on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary/3146509#3146509)