# javascript file reader on button click error: undefined refference

Tags: javascript, filestream

I'm trying to get a local file from a system, I did some searching and came around a way of doing this, when I tried to implement it in my code, I got the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

```js
document.getElementById('add-new-cat').addEventListener('click', handleFileSelect, false);

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;

    if(files.type.match('image.*')) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            
        })(files);

        var catIMG = reader.readAsBinaryString(files);
        alert(catIMG);    
    }   
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="cat_path_orig" id="cat-path-orig">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="add-new-cat">add</button>
```

I wouldn't know how to trigger the function with the file included, because I know it's looking for a value in the button that's being clicked

Comment: Where are you getting the error at? What line?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I provided the snippet

Comment: @epascarello I added a comment on the line where the error occurs

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's creating the same error for me, sorry, maybe I didn't translate it correctly? my errors show up in Dutch, maybe it's `Can't fetch the property type from an undefined refference or refference to an empty value`?

Comment: @Luuk: In the question, you said `target`, and pointed to the line reading `evt.target.files`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh, sorry, my bad, error is correct in the snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `click` event object doesn't have a `files` property. I think you're looking for the `files` property on the `input type="file"` object:

```js
document.getElementById('add-new-cat').addEventListener('click', handleFileSelect, false);

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = document.getElementById("cat-path-orig").files;   // ****

  console.log("files.length: " + files.length);
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(files, function(file) {
    console.log(file.name + ": " + file.type);
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="cat_path_orig" id="cat-path-orig">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="add-new-cat">add</button>
```

A couple of other notes:

1. You'll want to look at the `type` property on each individual file (see the snippet above). In your example, there will be only one (because there's no `multiple` attribute on the `input type="file"`), so you could just use `files[0]` rather than the loop I've used above.
2. Your use of `readAsBinaryString` is also incorrect; [here's an answer with a correct example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary/3146509#3146509).

Comment: perfect answer, again, sorry for the confusion, aparently dutch errors are quite different than english errors, I'll try my best to give correct english errors next time.