# Javascript read line by line text file

Tags: javascript, html, file, text, line

Javascript:

```
<script src="../plugin/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#test').click(function(){
           var txtFile = '../fileupload/mail.txt';
           var file = new File(txtFile);
           file.open("r");
           while (!file.eof) {
               alert(file.readln());
           }
           file.close();
       });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="test">Check</button>
```

When i click check button, Javascript will read file line by line. But it does not run :(. Please help me fix it

Comment: Do you know if the click event being fired?
i.e: have you put a `console.log` in the click function

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File

Answer (score 4):

You cannot read files that way from browser-hosted JavaScript. The [`File` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) doesn't accept just one argument, and [`File` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) don't have `open`, `readln`, or `close` methods nor an `eof` property. Whatever reference you're looking at, it's not for the browser-based `File` object.

If you're running this from a proper web page, you can read resources from your own server via ajax ([`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)).

If you're trying to read a local file, you'll have to have the **user** identify the file (you can't do it for them) via an `input type="file"`, and then use the [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) to read the contents of the file. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary/3146509#3146509) has an example of doing that (both in text and binary).

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to create and then download a file i would suggest that you take a look at [file saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

```
var blob = new Blob(["r"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "mail.txt");
```

else if you are looking to upload a file I would add a `input type="file" id="file-test"` and then use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

```
 $('#file-test').change(function(e) {
   var doc = event.target.files.document;
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(event) {
     // Then you can do something with the result
     console.log(event.target.result)
   };

   reader.readAsText(doc);
 }
```